# cut now has a line length limitation?

Tags: shell-script, openbsd, cut, utilities

I had a script, with a 25,000 character input that I was using 'cut' on:

```
...\n" | cut -c -$LENGTH
```

I didn't use it that frequently, but it was working (oh, about a year or two ago).  Granted, my sysadmins have probably run some updates, but I thought changes to basic utilities wouldn't be happening anymore.  It appears I was wrong.

Now it throws up an error:

```
cut: [-bcf] list: 3080 too large (allowed 1-2048)
```

...which isn't even a full page worth of text/characters in my terminal.

Are there any POSIX utilities that can take an arbitrary chunk out of a bigger chunk of text?  Or am I going to have to play with awk/sed/perl; and then worry about changes to those, every time I come to infrequently use this thing?

---

OpenBSD 6.4

No version for cut.  man says:

> The cut utility is compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 ("POSIX.1") specification.
>
> OpenBSD 6.4                    October 24, 2016                    OpenBSD 6.4

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your OS information and the implementation / version of `cut` that you are using (for example, the output of `cut --version` on a GNU/Linux system)

Comment: It seems to have been that way [almost forever](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blame/64679b8a256409e7a559e2283d78256de2449f87/usr.bin/cut/cut.c#L196). Note that limit there is [`_POSIX2_LINE_MAX`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_05), which should indeed be at least 2048, and is "Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file), when the utility is described as processing text files"

Comment: awk can set RS!=newline which POSIXly is  not text but still only required to support LINE_MAX. perl is not in POSIX at all. **`dd`** is _not_ text format (except conv=un/block), and I don't see any statement on supported length beyond describing a 'positive' multiple of 1024, but historically `dd` was used for tape drives which often required 4-16ki and sometimes more -- and worst case you can do `bs=b count=c` for b\*c bytes and if necessary add another `bs=p count=1`

Answer (score 5):

> compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 ("POSIX.1") specification

[This specification of `cut`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/cut.html) (as well as newer ones) says:

> The input files shall be text files, except that line lengths shall be unlimited

The following defines [text files](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_395):

> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length, including the <newline> character. […]

About [`{LINE_MAX}`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/basedefs/limits.h.html):

> `{LINE_MAX}`
> Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file), when the utility is described as processing text files. The length includes room for the trailing <newline>.
> Minimum Acceptable Value: `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}`
>
> `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}`
> Unless otherwise noted, the maximum length, in bytes, of a utility's input line (either standard input or another file), when the utility is described as processing text files. The length includes room for the trailing <newline>.
> Value: 2048

It looks like `cut` should not refuse to work with lines of arbitrary length, but it doesn't mean there mustn't be any limit to `-c` or `-b`. The constraint `allowed 1-2048` you observed is most likely because of (assumed) `{LINE_MAX}` or (fixed) `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}` (see [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/552706/108618#comment1026261_552706)).

In general `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}` should be a safe value. `{LINE_MAX}` may be bigger but it's at least `{_POSIX2_LINE_MAX}`, i.e. 2048.

Compare one of [the examples](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/cut.html#tag_20_28_17):

> Most utilities in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 work on text files. The cut utility can be used to turn files with arbitrary line lengths into a set of text files containing the same data. The paste utility can be used to create (or recreate) files with arbitrary line lengths. For example, if file contains long lines:
>
> ```
> cut -b 1-500 -n file > file1
> cut -b 501- -n file > file2
> ```
>
> creates `file1` (a text file) with lines no longer than 500 bytes (plus the <newline>) and `file2` that contains the remainder of the data from file. (Note that `file2` is not a text file if there are lines in file that are longer than `500 + {LINE_MAX}` bytes.) The original file can be recreated from `file1` and `file2` using the command:
>
> ```
> paste -d "\0" file1 file2 > file
> ```

This provides a POSIX method for "taking an arbitrary chunk out of a bigger chunk of text": cut 2048 or less bytes from the beginning of every line, as many times as you need to get your desired total. E.g. if you need 3080 bytes from each line, you may take 2000 bytes and then 1080 bytes from the remainder:

```
cut -b 1-2000 file > file1              # first 2000 bytes
cut -b 2001- file > file2               # remainder
cut -b 1-1080 file2 > file3             # following 1080 bytes
paste -d "\0" file1 file3 > file_final  # desired 3080 bytes (or less) per line
```

Note if you `cut` exactly 2048 bytes, the resulting lines with appended newline characters may exceed 2048 bytes and (if I interpret the documentation correctly) may not be considered text files. Therefore I would use at most 2047, just in case.

Comment: Wouldn't "cut -b 2001- file > file2" only work if the remainder is less than 2048? (or does it dump the remaining ~21k characters?)  How do I calculate the size of the data, if it is arbitrary input?

Comment: @user382423 According to the example it does dump the remaining ~21k characters. I'm not sure what you mean by `calculate the size of the data, if it is arbitrary input`. I think you need to do calculations based on your `$LENGTH`, not the input. The bigger `$LENGTH`, the more steps you need. I'm not sure how `-c` (as opposed to `-b`) should affect the calculation though. Experiment.

Comment: An aside: my (now current) version of cut requires a flag of -b,-c or -f.  Cut does not work with any of those options on larger sized inputs (>2048) sent its way via pipe.  (ie: as you said, it should - but it does not).

Comment: Kamil: Basically, if $LENGTH is arbitrary, I'm going to have to calculate and store how many cuts I need to do, make (and delete) an arbitrary number of files (and store values for names of files), determine if files were unable to be created/failed/collided with other files, make a couple of loops, etc.   A simpler POSIX solution, appears to be see if awk would handle it?

Comment: @user382423 Not necessarily arbitrary number of files. You can `paste` after each `cut`. This requires about four files at any given time. [POSIX `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) is required to handle `records terminated with the specified separator up to {LINE_MAX} bytes and may support longer records`. I think almost all POSIX tools are allowed to be limited by `{LINE_MAX}`. POSIX `cut` and `paste` deliberately support unlimited lines so one can process long lines *somehow* despite other tools being limited.

Answer (score 3):

The `cut` utility on OpenBSD has always restricted the end value of ranges given to the `-c` option to `_POSIX2_LINE_MAX` (which is 2048 on OpenBSD, see `getconf _POSIX2_LINE_MAX`).

In early 2018, a bug that caused a segmentation fault in the parsing of the command line options [was fixed](https://marc.info/?t=152215036200002&r=1&w=2).  The patch of the utility affects [the area of the code responsible for outputting the error that you see](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/cut/cut.c.diff?r1=1.23&r2=1.24&f=h), but I'm not certain that this changed the behaviour of the utility for your particular use case.  The utility should have complained about `-c -3080` even before this patch was applied.

To cut your file to an arbitrary line length using `cut`, see [Kamil's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552730/116858).

Another possibility is to switch over to Perl (which is available in the OpenBSD base system):

```
perl -pe '$_=substr($_,0,3080)' file
```

or, for an arbitrary `$LENGTH` length:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $len = $ARGV[0]; shift @ARGV } $_=substr($_,0,$len)' "$LENGTH" file
```

This emulates `cut -b`, for `cut -c` add the `-Mopen=locale` to the options for Perl.

This command would read from standard input if not given a filename.

Packaged into a shell function:

```sh
pcut () {
    perl -pe 'BEGIN { $len = $ARGV[0]; shift @ARGV } $_=substr($_,0,$len)' "$@"
}
```

This would be used as

```
some-command | pcut "$LENGTH"
```

Note that `sed` and `awk` (which are POSIX utilities) have the restriction that their input files must be *text files*.  A "text file" is in the strict POSIX sense a file with newline-delimited strings of length less than `_POSIX2_LINE_MAX` bytes.  Perl, not being a POSIX utility, is free of this restriction.

Comment: Note that that `perl` command would emulate `cut -b`, not `cut -c`. You'd need `perl -Mopen=locale ...` for `perl` to work with characters. (for UTF-8 data, see also the `-C` option and `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable).