# Are there any shell utilities on modern Unix-like operating systems that cannot operate on text files with really long lines?

Tags: shell, text-processing, posix

One can obtain the value of of `LINE_MAX` by running `getconf LINE_MAX`. On FreeBSD 12 and Ubuntu 18.04 (and I suspect many others) this value is 2048 bytes.

In POSIX world, there are many shell utilties that are specifically designed to work with text files. A file that has any one line that exceeds `LINE_MAX` bytes in length (newline inclusive) is not a text file (as defined by POSIX anyway). A shell utility designed to take text files as input is not required to be able to properly handle this kind of file.

In practice, I seem unable to find a utility that is unable to deal with text files with really long lines. It is my understanding that GNU utilities do not have any sort of real limit to how long a line in a text file can be (I'm not sure about FreeBSD).

Is anyone aware of a shell utility on any modern or semi-modern operating system that chokes on lines that exceed `LINE_MAX` bytes in length? As an aside, are programming languages like Perl and Python affected by the value of `LINE_MAX`?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/552706/70524

Answer (score 4):

There’s at least one example of a shell utility which sticks to `LINE_MAX`, at least in some circumstances, on this site, [OpenBSD `cut`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/552706/86440); it doesn’t *choke* on lines longer than those, but some of its capabilities are limited to the first `LINE_MAX` characters of a line.

In addition to utilities which outright refuse to work with longer lines, there is a common pattern which will cause potentially unwanted behaviour: input is often processed using

```c
fgets(line, sizeof line, fp);
```

where `line` is a `LINE_MAX`-sized character array (see for example [`pam_localuser`](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/v1.3.1/modules/pam_localuser/pam_localuser.c#L111)). If `line` is processed every time `fgets` returns non-`NULL`, then the input will be processed with lines split at `LINE_MAX` if they’re too long. Thus in `pam_localuser`, a line in `/etc/passwd` longer than `LINE_MAX` will be handled as two lines.

The programming languages and parser generators I looked at don’t have a reference to `LINE_MAX` (other than pass-through references, to make the value available to programs written in those languages). This includes GCC, Perl, Python, and Lua.

Comment: You are mistaken, there are implementations that work fine for infinite line length even when using `fgets()`. The real problem from using `fgets()` is that it cannot support lines that contain NUL bytes as it does not return the line length.

Comment: @schily I never said there weren’t. I said there are problems if the line is processed every time it’s retrieved using `fgets`, which is exactly what `pam_localuser` does.

Comment: The GNU reimplementation may behave this way. Solaris started in the mid 1990s to fill a NUL byte into the last position of the buffer before calling `fgets()` and reconstructs longer lines in case that the NUL has been replaced by a non `NL` character.

Comment: @schily and how does it deal with lines which are longer than the provided buffer?

Comment: Simply call `fgets()` repeatedly until the last position in the buffer is not overwritten, grow the line buffer between calls and append the following reads to the previous content of the buffer.

Comment: OK, same as the GNU version; the caller needs to deal with growing the buffer. So my point still stands; the question isn’t “how should utilities be written so that they can deal with lines of arbitrary lengths?”, and there are utilities which don’t deal with such lines correctly, and one common example is the use of `fgets` described in the answer (and yes, it’s incorrect, but it exists, which answers the question).